# How can I use a $elemMatch on first level array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Consider the following document:

```
{
  "_id" : "ID_01",
  "code" : ["001", "002", "003"],
  "Others" : "544554"
}
```

I went through this [MongoDB doc for elemmatch-query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/#elemmatch-query) & [elemmatch-projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/#elemmatch-projection), but not able to figure it out how to use the same for the above document.

Could anyone tell me how can I use `$elemMatch` for the field code?

Comment: Is `$in` really what you're looking for? [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/)

Comment: An example of your current query and the result you are trying to achieve would be very helpful.  It sounds like you do want an `$in` query.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll want to use the `$in` operator rather than `$elemMatch` in this case as `$in` can be used to search for a value (or values) inside a specific field. $in requires a list of values to be passed as an array. Additionally, and for your case, it will find either a single value, or by searching in an array of values. The entire matching document is returned.

For example, you might use it like this:

```
db.mycodes.find( { code: { $in: ["001"] } } )
```

Which could be simplified to just be:

```
db.mycodes.find({ code: "001" })
```

As MongoDB will look in an array for a single match like above (`"001"`).

Or if you want to search for `"001"` or `"002"`:

```
db.mycodes.find( { code: { $in: ["001", "002"] } } )
```

[$in documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/)

Comment: $in takes only arrays: "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $in needs an array"

Comment: @RaxWunter -- correct. Not sure why I had that as I did confirm it behaves that way as of 2.6. Thanks! (This was from April 2013 so something may changed in the console or DB ... not sure what happend :) )

Answer (score 5):

If you're simply looking to match all documents with an array containing a given value, you can just specify the value on the reference to that array, e.g.

```
db.mycodes.find( { code: '001' } )
```

Which thus would return you all documents that contained `'001'` in their `code` array